# PHP Setting custom header starting with ':'

Tags: php, curl, http-headers, request-headers

I need to setup some custom headers start with ":".

```
$option['headers'][] = ":authority: example.com"; //<-- Here is the problem
$option['headers'][] = "accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br";
$option['post'] = json_encode(array("Domain"=>"example.com"));
$url = "https://www.google.com";
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/62.0.3202.62 Safari/537.36");
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION,1);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE,"file.cookie");
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR,"file.cookie");
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HEADER,0);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $option['post']);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $option['headers']);
$getdata = curl_exec($ch);
```

I try to replace the ":" with chr(58) but same problem. I get error 55 and from log "* Failed sending HTTP POST request". If I comment first line is working, but I really need that header. I'm stuck here. Any solutions?

Comment: Why you need to setup some custom headers start with ":" ?

Comment: I want to replace the javascript (client-side) with php code (server-side).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`:authority:` looks like an HTTP/2 psuedo header, and you can't set them like this with curl. curl will however pass it on itself and it will use the same content as it would set for `Host:` to make it work the same way, independently of which HTTP version that is eventually used (it will also work with HTTP/3).